# iCloud Mail Folders Not Showing on Outlook on Windows

Tags: microsoft-outlook, icloud

Why aren't my iCloud folders aren't showing on Outlook?

[image: iCloud]

[image: Outlook]

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to figure this out, Google being no help, but it's very simple.

Right click on account in Outlook and choose "IMAP Folders"

[image: IMAP Folders]

Uncheck "When displaying hierarchy in Outlook, show only subscribed folders"

[image: Subscribe]

(Alternatively you can subscribe)